# different size of array in a struct c++ using a Template

Tags: c++

I have a typedef struct that contains an array with a different size, depends while running the app.
The app should read the size then it creates a struct with its specifics size of the array.
Here is the struct that I want to use it.

```
template <int N>
typedef struct Frame{
    float time;
    float zone_values[N];
}Frame;
```

My question is how can I call it in the main function?

Comment: Does this compile? The typedef is actually not necessary. Just use `struct Frame {...};` with template.

Comment: You must use a dynamic allocation. A template is not the right tool for this, unless you want to use different types.

Comment: This would be *way* better with `std::vector`. Is this a run-time variable, or a compile-time constant? If it's the former, you can't do it in regular C++. You need a container. If the latter then you *could* do it, but probably don't want to.

Comment: Note that you don't need `typedef` - just remove it (and the `Frame` after the `struct`).

Comment: A template is a compile-time mechanism, so the value `N` in your template must be specified at compile time.   If you want `N` to be read (e.g. from a file) then you need something that allows the size to be specified at run-time.   One option would be `std::vector<float>`  which can be dynamically resized (e.g. based on a value read at run time) as needed.

Comment: Given you correct the syntax, calling this struct in main function would look like this: `Frame<5> frame`. Hence the size of the array is not variable any more at run-time, but fixed to a certain number `N` at compile-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your struct has a non-type template (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)
which cannot be determined at runtime, you should instead use the answer provided by Sparkofska. If you still want to use a compile time version, you can do it like this with C++17

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N>
struct Frame {
    float time;
    std::array<float, N> zoneValues;
};

int main() {
    auto frame = Frame<3>{0.0f, std::array{1.0F, 2.0F, 3.0F}};
}
```

With C++20 you can also do

```cpp
auto frame = Frame{0.0f, std::array{1.0F, 2.0F, 3.0F}};
```

or alternatively add a deduction guide in c++17 like this

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N>
struct Frame {
    float time;
    std::array<float, N> zoneValues;
};

template<std::size_t N>
Frame(float, std::array<float, N>)->Frame<N>;

int main() {
    auto frame = Frame{0.0f, std::array{1.0F, 2.0F, 3.0F}};
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing up compile-time and run-time here. Your template parameter `N` must be known at compile time in order to compile. If you want to construct a collection of variable size based on runtime conditions, I'd suggest to use `std::vector` instead.

```cpp
struct Frame
{
    float time;
    std::vector<float> zone_values;

    Frame(const std::size_t size)
     : zone_values(size)
    {    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::size_t n = calc_some_size(...);
    Frame frame(n);
}
```

Use template as a tool when you know the size of the array before the program starts.

Use dynamically allocated containers (like std::vector) when you can determine the size of the array only while the program is already running.

Comment: Better for the constructor to initialise `zone_values` in the constructor's initialiser list  (e.g. `Frame(int size) : zone_values(size) {}`).    Also a `std::vector` does not use `int` to specify the size - it uses an (implementation-defined) `unsigned` type, typically `std::size_t`)

Comment: @Peter you're right, thanks. I adapted the code, but sometimes the point is better understandable and the code more readable with simplifications (like using int or omitting const)

Comment: I suggested nothing about using `const` - and, when passing by value, it is unnecessary.

Comment: I always get the same size here, which I don't want that

    Frame frame1(5);
    Frame frame2(1);
    std::cout<< sizeof (frame1)<<" "<<sizeof (frame2);
Always get 32 32

Comment: The [sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator gives you the number of bytes that the object occupies. That's not what you want. To get the number of elements use [std::vector::size()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) like so `size_t n_elements = frame1.size();`.